# How do I open a localhost pop-up in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Playing with pop-up right now and I can use it to access other sites (like Google), but not the localhost. Right now I have two basic pages. On localhost:8000 I have a simple page that says "Home" and has a pop-up button. On localhost:8000/calc/ I have a basic calculator. I'm attempting to create a pop-up that will open this calculator in a new window for the user to move, resize, and close at their leisure. This is my homepage right now:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <input type="button" value="Calculator" onclick="window.open('localhost:8000/calc/','_blank','height=500,width=500')" />
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

So I click on the pop-up button, but the window that opens says:

> The address wasn’t understood

Firefox doesn’t know how to open this address because one of the following protocols (localhost) isn’t associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.*

How do I get around this? Thanks!

Comment: Does adding `http://` fix it?

Comment: use a protocol scheme ... `http://localhost` or `https://localhost` or `//localhost`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments...it should work if you give it a protocol:

```
<input type="button" value="Calculator" onclick="window.open('http://localhost:8000/calc/','_blank','height=500,width=500')" />
```

The message from Firefox is quite specific - it's basically telling you that `localhost` isn't a valid protocol (which it isn't), so we can infer that the browser is examining the first part of the first parameter and expecting a [valid protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP).